# vs code jedi language server is running over 120.9% of CPU on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, cpu, python3, process

[image: python3 running over 120.9% of CPU (screenshot)]

I don't know why all of a sudden python3 decided to run over 120.9% of CPU but I'm facing this problem since last week and I still couldn't find out the solution.

I don't know why I can't find any application that is written in Python and that requires this much of CPU usage, as you can see clearly in that screenshot that only **python3** interpreter is using way too much of CPU.

I can't delete **python3**, if I do so I will crash my system, please post a solution to this problem.

I tried to find out the application that **python3's** interpreter was running using the solution given by **WinEunuuchs2Unix** and found out that it was **Visual Studio Code jedi language server** that was using this much of CPU.

[image]

Now help me to find out how to disable **jedi language server** support on Visual Studio Code (if there is nothing you can do with the CPU usage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem as suggested by a user `Iuabud` at [Rouge Python Processes with High CPU ...](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15586#issuecomment-792360066)

**Note:** *The steps I'm mentioning are only applicable if python's   `run-jedi-language-server.py` is consuming a lot of CPU in your system.*

1. Open the command palette (View > Command Palette...) or `Ctrl + Shift + P`.
2. Run the "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" command. This will open the user
   settings in VS code. **You don't want to open `defaultSettings.json` open
   `setting.json`**.
3. Paste the following line in the settings file:
   `"python.experiments.optOutFrom": ["pythonJediLSP"]` and save the file.
4. Reload the window (either by closing VS Code and opening it again or running
   the "Developer: Reload Window" command from the command palette),
   `Ctrl + Shift + P` and write the command `Reload Window`

**Edit:** It's been two days since I'm no more struggling with this problem so what I think is this is the solution of the problem.

### Update

Microsoft has released new **language server for python** called **Pylance**, if you had to disable **jedi-language-server** I would recommend going for **Pylance** as a language server for Python, here is a link to **Pylance** documentation [pylance-release](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release) go and check that out.

Comment: Note that Pylance has a proprietary license and gets automatically installed by the Python-extension. See https://www.easilyfascinated.com/2021/05/11/microsoft-pylance-and-licensing-sleight-of-hand

Answer (score 0):

Python by itself doesn't really consume any CPU. A program using `python3` is misbehaving and consuming too many resources. I use `ps` command instead:

```
$ ps aux | grep -v grep | grep python

root      1493  0.0  0.0 174652 19772 ?        Ssl  Apr06   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
rick      2903  0.3  0.1 626248 41228 ?        Sl   Apr06  10:19 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/indicator-sysmonitor
rick      4889  0.0  0.1 890152 49768 ?        Sl   Apr06   0:20 gedit /home/rick/python/mserve /home/rick/python/alienstart /home/rick/.bashrc /home/rick/python/location.py /home/rick/python/message.py
rick      5916  0.0  0.7 705836 251284 pts/22  Sl   Apr06   1:08 /usr/bin/python /home/rick/python/mmm
rick      6081  0.7  0.2 307000 83508 pts/22   Sl+  Apr06  21:31 python /home/rick/python/mserve
rick      6262  0.1  0.0 421952 30872 pts/22   Tl+  Apr06   5:28 python vu_meter.py stereo
```

Match the second column with the process ID that `htop` was reporting and then research that program.

Comment: You helped me find out the actual application that was using that much of CPU. Thank you @WinEunuuchs2Unix.